# Windows Phone profiling - parsing log failed

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, memory-profiling

I am newbie in memory profiling Windows Phone applications.
After I stopping memory profiling session Visual Studio tries to parse log, and failes with message "Parsing of log file failed".
I am see to the "ProfilerLog_" file in the %temp% directory and get this message:

```
System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '226295856'  Key being added: '226295856'
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.CFAdapter.HandleEvent(UInt32 eventID, ProbeMarkerType eventMarkerType, Double clockTime, Double threadTime, UInt32 threadID, ThreadType threadType, List`1 eventInfoList)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.WPInputAdapter.HandleEvent(ProbeEventSource eventSource, UInt32 eventID, ProbeMarkerType eventMarkerType, Double clockTime, Double threadTime, UInt32 threadID, ThreadType threadType, List`1 eventInfoList)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.WPInputAdapter.HandleEvent(BinaryReader input, Int64 endOffset, ThreadStreamInfo threadStreamInfo)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.WPInputAdapter.HandleEvents()
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.WPInputAdapter.ParseLogFile(BinaryReader input, String logFilename, AgLogFileHeader header)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.WPInputAdapter.Parse(Object data)
   at SilverlightProfiler.Internal.ViewModel.AnalyzingViewModel.startAnalyzing()
```

May be somebody have faced with this problem and find some solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem. I deleted all files from my temp folder and profiling started working again. Not sure if that was only a coincidence but maybe worth trying.

Comment: which temp folder are you referring to?

Comment: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp